Number of a, b and c is even
The language of strings over $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that the number of $a$ is even, the number of $b$ is even and the number of $c$ is even is clearly regular (it is easy to construct a FA or a RE for this language). However, I cannot find a simple and intuitive context-free grammar that generates this language. Any guess?
Thanks in advance,
Marcus.

Using a finite automaton, it is quite easy to construct a regular grammar for the same language.
Given $A = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$ a complete DFA, consider $G = (\Sigma, V, P, S)$ the grammar defined by:

$V = Q$, that is each state is a variable;
$S = q_0$, the starting variable is the initial state;
for each $q\in F$, $q\to \varepsilon\in P$;
for each $q\in Q$ and $a\in \Sigma$, $q\to a\delta(q, a)\in P$.

Then $L(A) = L(G)$.

Yes. But then I have to solve a regular system with 8 equations and 8 variables, which leads to a pretty big and ugly contex-free gramar. My questions is whether there is a simple, concise and natural context-free grammar for this language. I have been trying for many days now without success.

Why are you talking about solving a regular system? There is no regular system, from the finite automaton, you can construct the grammar mechanically without solving anything.

But that would be a right linear grammar. I am looking for a context-free non-right linear grammar. Solving the regular system (obtained from the right linear grammar) would be a way of getting it, but the result is too complex.

Why are you looking for a non-right linear grammar? Also, you didn't say so in your question. And here's a trick: create a right linear grammar, and add a new start symbol $S'$ and a rule $S'\to S$. Tada! The new grammar is not right linear! (not but seriously, I do not understand why that is a problem)

Sorry that I forgot to say that. I am lloking for a context-free non-right linear grammar that generates this language. Preferably a natural and simple grammar, not an artificial  and complex (with many rules) one. Does it exist?

Take a left linear grammar instead.

For all $i,j,k \in \{0,1\}$ create a non terminal $A_{ijk}$ for the language of strings where $i,j,k$ are the parity of the number of $a,b,c$, respectively.
You can then easily connect these non terminals using productions and make a linear CFG. E.g., $A_{ijk} \to a A_{i'jk}$ where $i' = 1-i$, the analogous for $j$ and $k$, and $A_{000} \to \epsilon$.
Alternatively, you can use $A_{ijk} \to A_{i'j'k'}A_{i''j''k''}$ for all indices such that $i = i' + i'' ({\sf mod}\ 2)$ and the analogous for $j,k$. Then add the base cases $A_{100} \to a,A_{010} \to b,A_{001} \to c$ as well as $A_{000} \to \epsilon$.

Thanks, but still it is a regular equation system. If solved, it will produce a big and complex context-free grammar. Does a simple and natural context-free non-right linear grammar exists for this language?

@Marcus The last alternative is not really regular/linear, but it does use a large number of productions. I'd guess you can't do this with a truly small number of productions.

@chi Interesting. We can use this approach to avoid one of your variables, by generating two $a$'s at the same time: $A_{jk} \to B_{j'k'} a B_{j''k''} a A_{j'''k'''}$. Here the $B$'s indicate strings without $a$'s (but that is not essential). I agree, there seems no elegant solution that is better than the finite automaton we started with.
